# How to use messageUI.framework in phone gap?

Tags: jquery, iphone, objective-c, xcode, cordova

hi I am developing one IOS phonegap application. here I need to send email from app so hence i am  using  messageUI.framework but I don't know how to implement it.

this is my html send email button with java script function.

```
<input id="EMAIL" type="submit" onClick='gomail()' data-theme="b" value="Send E-mail"  data-mini="false">

function gomail()
       {
       alert("mail");
       }
```

this is my MainControllerView.h

```
#import <Cordova/CDVViewController.h>
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>

    @interface MainViewController : CDVViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
   // how to invoke html button event here .... 

    @end
```

And this is my MainControllerView.m

```
- (IBAction)send:(id)sender {


    MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer;
    mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate=self;

    NSArray *emailAddresses;
    emailAddresses=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"test@gmail.com", nil];

    NSString *sendSubject = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",self.latitude.text];
    NSString *sendMessage = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",self.longitude.text];

    [mailComposer setToRecipients:emailAddresses];
    [mailComposer setSubject:sendSubject];
    [mailComposer setMessageBody:sendMessage isHTML: NO];
    [self presentModalViewController:mailComposer animated:YES];

}

- (void) mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

This is the code for sending email.

How can we link from html to MainControllerView.h and MainControllerView.m ?

Please suggest me the link between them.

Please suggest me a way to go back to html5 app from a native app.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to use a PhoneGap plugin to help you through this you can find one that I have [forked here](https://github.com/whodeee/email-composer) based off of the `EmailComposerWithAttachments` plugin. It handles everything you are looking for and it also adds the capability of easily adding attachments if you decide to go that route as well.

Edit: Added plugin install info

To add the plugin

1. navigate to your project folder with the Terminal (for mac)
2. type in the following `phonegap plugin add https://github.com/whodeee/email-composer`
3. That will add the plugin to your project
4. to use the plugin, call it with this javascript method `window.plugins.emailComposer.showEmailComposerWithCallback(callback,subject,body,toRecipients,ccRecipients,bccRecipients,isHtml,attachments,attachmentsData);` referenced from the github link above

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But in plugin.xml config file is targeted to config.xml. i.e;         <config-file target="config.xml" parent="/*">
                <feature name="EmailComposer">
                <param name="ios-package" value="EmailComposer" />
            </feature>
        </config-file> . But there is no config.xml in my project. how can I configure config.xml to my project. I have created my project through command line tool so config file is not created. Is there any alternative way to create config.xml

Comment: did you install the plugin using CLI?

Comment: No I did not install using CLI. Can you guide me how to install plugin using CLI ?

Comment: updated the answer to include the install steps - you can check out the plugin documentation [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface)

Comment: I tried to install plugin but I am not able to install. I have got below error message.  For your reference :: AX-MC-RND-110:SimpleGps homebhat$ phonegap plugin add https://github.com/whodeee/email-composer;
-bash: phonegap: command not found